# Statsmodels MANOVA : IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Tags: python, statsmodels, manova

I have spent hours trying to make statsmodels do my MANOVA without success.
Here is the code:

```
from statsmodels.multivariate.manova import MANOVA 

df = data
feats_list = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3' ... 'col4']
var_list = ['col5', 'col6']
endog, exog = np.asarray(df[feats_list]), np.asarray(df[var_list])
manov = MANOVA(endog, exog)
manov.mv_test()
```

Providing:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-16-c3fc1d1f16f6> in <module>()
          1 manov = MANOVA(endog, exog)
    ----> 2 manov.mv_test()

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\multivariate\manova.py in mv_test(self, hypotheses)
         68                     name = 'x%d' % (i)
         69                     L = np.zeros([1, self.exog.shape[1]])
    ---> 70                     L[i] = 1
         71                     hypotheses.append([name, L, None])
         72 

    IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 

1
```

I tried also to put the hypotheses by myself and I always get a SingularMatrixError so I suppose that I am not using the class correctly.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't seem to be the problem...

Comment: (I deleted my incorrect previous comment) This looks like a bug. The L or L[i] looks wrong. It looks like there are no unit tests for the case without using formulas.

Comment: I opened https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/4903

Answer (score 1):

Based on [issue 4903](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/4903) referenced by Josef in the comments above, the following would work

```
from statsmodels.multivariate.manova import MANOVA 

feats_list = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
var_list = ['col5', 'col6']
df = pd.DataFrame(
         np.random.random_sample(size=(100,6)),
         columns=feats_list + var_list
       )
endog, exog = np.asarray(df[feats_list]), np.asarray(df[var_list])


mod = MANOVA.from_formula('col1 + col2 + col3 + col4 ~ col5 + col6', data=df)
r = mod.mv_test()
print(r)

                 Multivariate linear model
============================================================

------------------------------------------------------------
       Intercept        Value  Num DF  Den DF F Value Pr > F
------------------------------------------------------------
          Wilks' lambda 0.3420 4.0000 94.0000 45.2047 0.0000
         Pillai's trace 0.6580 4.0000 94.0000 45.2047 0.0000
 Hotelling-Lawley trace 1.9236 4.0000 94.0000 45.2047 0.0000
    Roy's greatest root 1.9236 4.0000 94.0000 45.2047 0.0000
------------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------
          col5          Value  Num DF  Den DF F Value Pr > F
------------------------------------------------------------
          Wilks' lambda 0.9297 4.0000 94.0000  1.7775 0.1399
         Pillai's trace 0.0703 4.0000 94.0000  1.7775 0.1399
 Hotelling-Lawley trace 0.0756 4.0000 94.0000  1.7775 0.1399
    Roy's greatest root 0.0756 4.0000 94.0000  1.7775 0.1399
------------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------
          col6          Value  Num DF  Den DF F Value Pr > F
------------------------------------------------------------
          Wilks' lambda 0.9891 4.0000 94.0000  0.2590 0.9035
         Pillai's trace 0.0109 4.0000 94.0000  0.2590 0.9035
 Hotelling-Lawley trace 0.0110 4.0000 94.0000  0.2590 0.9035
    Roy's greatest root 0.0110 4.0000 94.0000  0.2590 0.9035
============================================================
```